# Tokenize problem in Java with separator ". "

Tags: java, string, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I need to split a text using the separator `". "`. For example I want this string :

```
Washington is the U.S Capital. Barack is living there.
```

To be cut into two parts:

```
Washington is the U.S Capital. 
Barack is living there.
```

Here is my code :

```
// Initialize the tokenizer
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("Washington is the U.S Capital. Barack is living there.", ". ");
 while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
      System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());

}
```

And the output is unfortunately :

```
Washington
is
the
U
S
Capital
Barack
is
living
there
```

Can someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't use `StringTokenizer`; it's a legacy class. Use [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) or simply [`String.split`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) instead.

```
    String text = "Washington is the U.S Capital. Barack is living there.";
    String[] tokens = text.split("\\. ");
    for (String token : tokens) {
        System.out.println("[" + token + "]");
    }
```

This prints:

```
[Washington is the U.S Capital]
[Barack is living there.]
```

Note that `split` and `Scanner` are "regex"-based (regular expressions), and since `.` is a special regex "meta-character", it needs to be escaped with `\`. In turn, since `\` is itself an escape character for Java string literals, you need to write `"\\. "` as the delimiter.

This may sound complicated, but it really isn't. `split` and `Scanner` are much superior to `StringTokenizer`, and regex isn't that hard to pick up.

#### Regular expressions tutorials

- [Java Lessons/Regular expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)
- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - Very good tutorial, not Java specific

#### Related questions

- [Scanner vs. StringTokenizer vs. String.Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691184/scanner-vs-stringtokenizer-vs-string-split)

#### API Links

- [`java.util.StringTokenizer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

  - `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.
- [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

  - A simple text scanner which can parse primitive types and strings using regular expressions.
  - [Java Tutorials - Basic I/O - Scanning and formatting](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/scanfor.html)
- [`String[] String.split`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

  - Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

---

#### But what went wrong?

The problem is that `StringTokenizer` takes **each character** in the delimiter string as individual delimiters, i.e. **NOT** the entire `String` itself.

From the API:

> [`StringTokenizer(String str, String delim)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29): Constructs a string tokenizer for the specified string. **The characters in the `delim` argument are the delimiters for separating tokens.** Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Your StringTokenizer constructor takes the delimiter ". " which matches dot or space as delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating the blank space after the dot in the delimiter. Use this instead.

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer("Washington is the U.S Capital. Barack is living there.", ".");
```

Comment: That will split "U.S" as well

Comment: @josek.. oops.. sorry, i didn't notice it :)

Answer (score 0):

- StringTokenizer(String str)     : creates StringTokenizer with specified  string.
- StringTokenizer(String str, String delim) : creates    StringTokenizer with specified string and delimiter.
- StringTokenizer(String str, String delim, boolean    returnValue) : creates StringTokenizer with specified string, delimiter and returnValue.

  If a return value is true, delimiter characters are considered to be tokens. If it is false, then delimiter characters serve to separate tokens.