# Convert CSV to Set<String> in Java

Tags: java, tokenize

I have a comma-seperated value string in Java:

```
String s = "a,b,c,d";
```

I need to tokenize it (with comma as the delimiter) and turn it into a `Set<String>`. Is `StringTokenizer` my best bet or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: you would find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2972215/1001027

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you try to solve generally CSV parsing to set be aware that there are quotes and coma escaping to handle. This is why libraries like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) exist. Otherwise you just need to do as hvgotcodes described.

Answer (score 3):

Try String.split(), that's probably the easiest.

```
    String[] a = "a,b,c,d".split( "," );
    Set<String> s = new HashSet( Arrays.asList( a ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Although `StringTokenizer` is a good option to split your input string, I personally prefer using `String.split()`.

```
String[] tokens = myString.split(",");
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(tokens));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `split`.  `split` gives you an array, so

`String[] toks = s.split(",")`

and then

`Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(toks));`

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework/) provides [`StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToSet`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#commaDelimitedListToSet%28java.lang.String%29) that does exactly what you're after.  It's probably overkill to pull in Spring just for this, but if you're working in a framework that already includes it then it's an option to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a simple solution without all CSV rules I would recommend [`StringUtils.split`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20char%29) (instead `String.split` due the regex overhead):

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(text, ',')));
```

If you need a solution that obeys the CSV rules, you should think in use [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/csv/)