# How to split a string with two empty lines in java using regex pattern for unix server

Tags: java, regex, string, unix

in windows following regex pattern is working: ("\r\n\r\n?\n\r")
But I tried with forward slashes, but not working on server.
Sample Data to split:

```
ABC
XYZ


NMB
YHJ

VGH
```

So, after splitting above data we want 2 arrays of string like

```
string[0] = ABC
XYZ
string[1] = NMB
YHJ

VGH
```

Comment: why forward slashes?  try double backward slashes

Comment: You might be a bit confused between directory separators and escape characters (backslashes) . The former is different across OSs, the latter is always the same.

Comment: Why are there only two entries in the output array?  I would have expected three.  Please explain your logic here.

Comment: Also, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516957/how-do-i-use-system-getpropertyline-separator-tostring/3517108) interesting

Comment: Since Java 8 regex supports `\R` to represent many form of line separators. So try maybe with `split("\\R{2}")` (`{2}` shows better IMO that you want exactly two line separators).

Answer (score 0):

the line separator is different in different os. you should get line separator first.

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Comment: A good suggestion, but this doesn't explain how to generate the output the OP wants here.

Comment: Actually, the separator will usually depend on OS where the file was created, which can easily be a different computer than where it's read. It's better to support both (all?) line separator formats unless you know for sure what the separator is in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, suppose we have a string and want to separate it:

```
String s = "ABC\nXYZ\n\n\nNMB\nYHJ\n\nVGH";
String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String[] results = s.split(separator + separator);
System.out.println(results[0]);
// returns ABC
//         XYZ
```

Also you maybe want to split them again:

```
for (String res : results) {
    System.out.println(res.split(separator)[0]);
    // returns ABC
 }
```