# JSP: Code to Refresh File

Tags: java, xml, jsp

currently I am working with XML, JSP, and Activiti Workflow Engine. On my project, I have following processes:

- An employee submit a JSP Form
- When the form is submitted, I will update my xml file to change the name of a tag. For example, from: "Sign Document" into "Sign Document 1". 1 here represent the ID of the data in my database
- After the file has successfully updated, the program will directly deploy Activiti Workflow Engine Process based on my updated XML file

I have successfully update my xml file and deploy the process, but when I got some problem with the name of the XML tag. The problem is:

- After the XML file successfully updated, my program will not directly used the latest file, but it used the old one. So for example, before I update the XML file, the name of the tag is "Sign Form" and after I updated the file, the tag name on the file will become "Sign Form 1". However, when I check my activiti database, it shows that activiti still used the xml file with tag name "Sign Form" not "Sign Form 1"

I guess it because I need to refresh the XML file first before run the deployment. But I don't know how to do so on JSP or Java. Anyone could help me? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
try {
            String filepath = "path/to/the/filename.bpmn20.xml";
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

            // Get the process element by tag name directly
            Node userTask = doc.getElementsByTagName("userTask").item(0);

            // update userTask attribute
            NamedNodeMap attr = userTask.getAttributes();
            Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("name");
            nodeAttr.setTextContent("Review and Sign Form "+id);

            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

            System.out.println("Done");

           } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
           } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
           } catch (SAXException sae) {
            sae.printStackTrace();
           }
```

Comment: how to commit the changed?

Comment: Can you post the code how you are updating the xml in database?

Comment: i dont think it is a problem from my xml file. but, on my java code:

Here is my java code:

<code>
ch.changeBO(id+1);
dp.deployProcess();
</code>

ch.changeBO(id+1) was used to changed the XML file
and
dp.deployProcess() was used to deploy the process (which will used my xml file)

And I think the problem is I tried to use my xml file without refresh them, so the compiler didnt notice the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just read file, replace the string of XML content and write the revised content back to XML.

Reference: [Find and replace words/lines in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935791/find-and-replace-words-lines-in-a-file)