# Convert Integer to specific String format

Tags: java, json, string, integer

I have an integer value, say `int id` whose value i get runtime by getter function.
I want to replace this value of `id` in place of `"VALUE"` from .json like as follows

`{
  "id":"VALUE",
  "name": "Name updated",
  "description": "description Updated",
  "active": false
}`

I found following way to replace it if `id` is `String`,

```
String str = "myJson.json";
str.replace("\"VALUE\"", "\"id\"");
```

How can i use int id in above function with this format "\"id\"" ?
Any other solution are welcome.

EDIT:

```
String str = "myJson.json";
```

is wrong way to get json content into String.

Comment: `str.replace("\"VALUE\"", "\"" + id + "\"");` ? Or simpler: `str.replace("VALUE", "" + id);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did in following way.
To replace content of Json file need to convert contents in to String. I did this with help of following function.

```
public static String loadJson(String jsonFileName) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(jsonFileName);
    return IOUtils.toString(stream);
}
```

Then declare a String variable,

```
String editedJson = loadJson(TEST_SET + "myJson.json");
editedJson.replace("VALUE", "" + id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple `regex` replace, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "{\"id\":\"VALUE\",\"name\": \"Name updated\",\"description\": \"description Updated\",\"active\": false}";
    int id = 5;
    value = value.replaceAll("\"VALUE\"", String.valueOf(id));
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: I do not have String. I have a Json file and int id. I need to convert the string again into the Json file. I am really new in .json  kind of things. :(

Comment: Here is the example to replace content in files, all we need to do is to use the above example and replace String : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935791/find-and-replace-words-lines-in-a-filehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935791/find-and-replace-words-lines-in-a-file

Answer (score 0):

Using org.json library you can assign it to JSON Object and Use the put method:

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(YOUR_STRING);
String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(jsonObject);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.toJSONArray(new JSONArray(names));

 JSONObject id=  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("id");
    person.put("VALUE", id);
```

regex replace may create some issue by replace someother matching string .

Comment: i did this. but `jsonArray`can not be resolved. No import option appears rather asking me to create new variable.

Comment: you can use toJSONArray() to convert a JSONObject to JSONArray.I have edited my answer.