# Troubleshooting Java replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am trying to write a method that accepts an input string to be found and an input string to replace all instances of the found word and to return the number of replacements made. I am trying to use pattern and matcher from JAVA regex.  I have a text file called "text.txt" which includes "this is a test this is a test this is a test". When I try to search for "test" and replace it with "mess", the method returns 1 each time and none of the words test are replaced.

```
public int findAndRepV2(String word, String replace) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{
    int cnt = 0; 

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(this.filename));
    Writer fw = new FileWriter("test.txt");
    String line = input.readLine();


    while (line != null)
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(word, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {matcher.replaceAll(replace); cnt++;}

        line = input.readLine();
    }
    fw.close();
    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and replace words/lines in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935791/find-and-replace-words-lines-in-a-file)

Comment: You want to replace a literal string. Why would you use a regex? Also, replaceAll doesn't return the number of replacements, so how could it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to ensure that the text you are searching for is not interpreted as a regex. You should do:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(word), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Second, `replaceAll` does something like this:

```
public String replaceAll(String replacement) {
    reset();
    boolean result = find();
    if (result) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        do {
            appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
            result = find();
        } while (result);
        appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

Note how it calls `find` until it can't find anything. This means that your loop will only be run once, since after the first call to `replaceAll`, the matcher has already found everything.

You should use `appendReplacement` instead:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(buffer, replace);
    cnt++;
}
buffer.append(line.substring(matcher.end()));
// "buffer" contains the string after the replacement
```

I noticed that in your method, you didn't actually do anything with the string after the replacement. If that's the case, just count how many times `find` returns true:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    cnt++;
}
```