# How to compile and run java programs ignoring package info?

Tags: java, javac

I have a pile of .java files.  They all have the same class name `public MyClass`.  They all have a `main` method.  They all may or may not have a `package` declaration at top, and I do not know ahead of time.

I am trying to write a script to compile and run these java programs.  This is easy for the files without the `package` declaration... I just do some `cp` operations to setup, `javac MyClass.java` and `java MyClass`, then `rm` to teardown.  However, the files with the `package` declaration require special attention.  I have a few options that occur to me, including deleting the `package` lines, or attempting to *read* the `package` lines so that I know what the resulting directory structure should be.  Both of these require me to go parsing through the `.java` files, which makes me sad.

Is there a way to compile and run these files without having to parse the `.java` files? Something like:

```
javac --ignore_package_structure MyClass.java
```

would be ideal, but a quick look at the `javac` man pages suggests that such a thing doesn't exist.

Comment: You're saying that all your files are named `MyClass.java`? The public class name must be identical with the file name (without the `.java`).

Comment: Yes, they are all named `MyClass.java`.  What I mean here is that I have many different java programs (these are student submissions).  I would like to compile and run them all separately.

Comment: `(these are student submissions)` when you run a `MyClass` file, how do you decide which student gets credit for the result?

Comment: @ublec Only if the class is `public`, and it doesn't have to be, to be executed.

Comment: @markspace the files are organized, so I know which file belongs to whom...

Comment: Can we know how the files are organized then?  It might bear on the problem of how to execute them.

Comment: I suppose I can organize them however.  Currently I'm just putting them in `[student_identifier]/MyClass.java`

Answer (score 3):

If we can *assume* that each student submits a single source file named `HelloWorld.java`, then we can use the "Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs" feature added by [JEP 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) in **Java 11**:

```
java HelloWorld.java
```

We don't run `javac` first, we don't get a `.class` file (no cleanup needed), and any `package` declaration is handled automatically.

Remember, the students are still allowed to use many classes, they just all have to be submitted to you in a single source file.

The name of the class doesn't even matter. The first class in the source file is executed.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any easy way to do this. You could use regex though, and replace all imports with this simple java regex:

```
"package \w+;"g
```

Simply stated, you create a Java program to replace all the package names.
How to replace files: [Find and replace words/lines in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935791/find-and-replace-words-lines-in-a-file)