# Querying text file into database

Tags: android, sql, database, text, gtfs

My Program needs to be able to scan a text file, and store the values of the text file into a database.
Suppose I've read in a line of code that looks like this

```
3,95003,"ALLENDALE",,41.030902,-74.130957,2893
```

I want to be able to call a part of the string and store it as a database value.  How exactly would I do that?  I already know how to read in text files, but i need to know how to filter and only grab a part of them.

In a database I would usually add a value by doing something like this.

```
values.put("A", "B");
```

How can i read a value from only part of the textfile into B?

Say I want it to display values.put("A", "ALLENDALE").

Answer:

```
AgencyString = readText();
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.letter);

        tv.setText(readText());

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(AgencyString, ",");
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            tv.setText(st.nextToken());
        }
    }

    private String readText() {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.agency);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int i;
        try {
            i = inputStream.read();
            while (i != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                i = inputStream.read();
            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();

    }
```

The next step for me is to store these values seperated into an array, and read them into my database.  I was able to filter through my agency.txt file by using a StringTokenizer method and setting a 'comma' as my delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at. Use  delimiters ",".
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: I am pretty sure this is exactly waht i need,this also helps me answer a question I had in the past, Thanks!
StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");

Comment: StringTokenizer is deprecated better try using split method or Scanner class.

Comment: it still works though,  Will scanner class be more efficient?

Comment: Compare [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691184/scanner-vs-stringtokenizer-vs-string-split