# android split url String

Tags: android, string, split

My String look like this

```
String url = 'domain1/balabala.mp3,domain2/aaaaa.mp3,domain3/baaaaa.mp3';
```

I want out put Like this

```
String domain1 = 'domain1/balabala.mp3';
String domain2 = 'domain2/aaaaa.mp3';
String domain3 = 'domain3/baaaaa.mp3';
```

Ex: Where host name called 'domain1' get the link as String

EDITED: I dont Want Just a Array. I need Out put based on domain host name.
All Answer is good. Pls check again.

This one Nearly Work but not i Expected..

```
String[] separated = CurrentString.split(",");
separated[0]; // this will contain "domain1"
separated[1];// this will contain "domain2"
```

But this one Not Based host name.. It just separate first ,second and third domain name

Comment: have u tried String.split to split current string?

Comment: All answers are good, but imho there is also StringTokenizer, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691184/scanner-vs-stringtokenizer-vs-string-split .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try split..

```
String[] domains = "domain1/balabala.mp3,domain2/aaaaa.mp3,domain3/baaaaa.mp3".split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split on the comma, this gives you an array which makes more sense than declaring variables as your string I assume may contain a different number of domains.

```
final String url = "domain1/balabala.mp3,domain2/aaaaa.mp3,domain3/baaaaa.mp3";
final String[] split = url.split(",");
for(final String domain : split) {
    System.out.println(domain);
}
```

Comment: I need Separate String Name for each domain Example " IF LIKE '%domain1%' in String url " output is  String domain1 = "domain1/balabala.mp3";.  Sorry my bad English

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "domain1/balabala.mp3,domain2/aaaaa.mp3,domain3/baaaaa.mp3";
    String[] strAry = url.split(",");
    for (int i=0; i<strAry.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(strAry[i]);
    }
```