# Difference between using StringTokenizer and String.split( )?

Tags: java, string, split, stringtokenizer

I've been using `String[] split(String)` of `String` class to split any string for some given delimiter, and it worked fine.

However, now it is expected to re-factor the same logic with `StringTokenizer`. But what are the differences and benifits of using one over the other.

Also, I feel that `String[]` returned by `split()` in a single call is much efficient option than using the objects of the class `StringTokenizer`.

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691184/scanner-vs-stringtokenizer-vs-string-split

Comment: StringTokenizer is rarely used these days.  I would have a look at Scanner.

Answer (score 22):

Take a look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.
>
> The following example illustrates how the String.split method can be
>   used to break up a string into its basic tokens:
>
> ```
>  String[] result = "this is a test".split("\\s");
>  for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
>      System.out.println(result[x]);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`String#split` accepts a regular expression whether `StringTokenizer` just accepts a `String` by which will split the string. You should always stick to the `String#split`, it's more robust then StringTokenizer.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its      use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use       the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following program,

The string "x" is a tab separated 
12s34;

```
    public class Testoken {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String x = "1   2   s       3           4   ";
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(x,"\t");
            int i = 0;
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                System.out.println("token-->"+st.nextToken());            
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println("i-->"+i);//elements from tokenizer
            String [] a = x.split("\t");
            System.out.println("length--->"+a.length);
            for(int y = 0;y<a.length;y++){
            System.out.println("value-->"+a[y]);//elements from split
            }
        }
    }   





Output: 

token-->1 
token-->2 
token-->s 
token-->3 
token-->4 
i-->5 
length--->8 
value-->1 
value-->2 
value-->s 
value--> 
value-->3 
value--> 
value--> 
value-->4
```

Comment: Output: 

token-->1 
token-->2 
token-->s 
token-->3 
token-->4 
i-->5 
length--->8 
value-->1 
value-->2 
value-->s 
value--> 
value-->3 
value--> 
value--> 
value-->4

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html
say:

StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

So I would say, don't change it and show that line to the person who recommended refactoring it. Maybe they have old information or another good reason to tell you.