# tokenizing input using split

Tags: java, split, token

I am using the StringToken class to tokenize my input as follows:

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(input); 
n = tokens.countTokens();
a = tokens.nextToken()
```

However, I found that split is more efficient, is there a way how to get the number of tokens (instead of countTokens) and a way to get the next token if I use split?

Comment: Strange, StringTokenizer should be as twice fast/effcient, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677919/difference-between-using-stringtokenizer-and-string-split

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
String str = "aa,bb,cc,dd";
String[] token = str.split(",");

System.out.println("Size of tokens: " + token.length);

//Printing out all tokens
for(int x=0; x<token.length; x++)  //A few different ways to print out the token values
    System.out.println(token[x]);
```

`string.split()` method will return you with a `string array`. So now you can treat each token element as a string array element. In the above codes, token is just a String array.

**OUTPUT:**

```
Size of tokens: 4
aa
bb
cc
dd
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: And _a way to get the next token if I use split_.

Comment: Actually I don't quite get what he meant by `get next token`.

Comment: `aa` is the first token. `bb` is the second token. The next token after `bb` is `cc`.

Comment: i mean get the next word, like if i have hello world i need to get first hello then world

Comment: Wouldn't token[0], token[1]..etc get the thing you want? Am I interpreting your question wrongly?

Comment: That's how I understand it too. But you should put it in your answer. Also, it would be good to print that all the tokens are calculated at once, while `nextToken` would only get the next.

Comment: Ok, I guess you want something like a .next() which test whether the next one exist?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you looking for:

```
String str = "A,B,C,D";
String[] token = str.split(",");
ArrayList<String> tokList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(token));
Iterator<String> tok = tokList.iterator();

while(tok.hasNext())                //Check whether next element exsit
    System.out.print(tok.next());   //Print out the token string 1 by 1
```

**Program Output:** ABCD

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have `String abcd = "a-b-c-d";`
You can perform a split on this one. You'll get: `String[] stringArray = abcd.split("-");`
If you have the StringArray, you could get the size by using `stringArray.length` (and save the result to an `int`.
If you want to get the "next token", you can simply iterate over the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    String tempString = stringArray[i];
    //do something with the String
}
```

Is that what you are looking for?