# Multiple regex uses in split method

Tags: java, regex, string

if in my String  two regex are continuous [comma(,) and space( )] so I want to treat one regex so what should I do.

```
String s = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?";
String str[]=s.split("[!._,'@? ]");
```

**My output is:-**

```
11
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
space( )
isn
t
he
```

**I want this:-**

```
10
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
isn
t
he
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same result with StringTokenizer as well.
Here is the code segment:-

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s," !@,.?_'");
    System.out.println(str.countTokens());
    while(str.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(str.nextToken());
}
```

To know the difference between StringTokenizer and split() check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677919/difference-between-using-stringtokenizer-and-string-split)

Answer (score 3):

Consume both tokens on the split, just add `+` to your pattern to indicate that it should match one **or** more; like,

```
String[] str = s.split("[!._,'@? ]+");
```