# Splitting a string in two parts if p

Tags: java, string, split

I am attempting to split a word from its punctuation:

So for example if the word is `"Hello?"`. I want to store `"Hello"` in one variable and the `"?"` in another variable.

Here is my code so far:

```
    String inWord = "hello?";
    if (inWord.contains(","+"?"+"."+"!"+";")) {

        String parts[] = inWord.split("\\," + "\\?" + "\\." + "\\!" + "\\;");
        String word = parts[0];
        String punctuation = parts[1];
    } else {
        String word = inWord;
    }

    System.out.println(word);
    System.out.println(punctuation);
```

My problem is that I am getting error: cannot find symbol when I try and print out the word and the punctuation.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: You understand that [`+` != `or`]?

Comment: The scope of a variable declaration like `String word = ...` is only the block (the pieces of code inside '{' and '}') that it's in. The variables `word` and `punctuation` don't exist in the scope in which you try to print them.

Comment: Also you might better use String.matches instead String.contains

Comment: It is good practice on StackOverflow to also print your error message completely. Yours, as @ErwinBolwidt pointed out, would have been a compile error. This way the question can be found be the next person  having the same error message. Chances are the cause of the error is also similar.

Comment: The `split` method deletes the delimiter, which means you wouldn't conserve the punctuation character http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

There are other things wrong with your code but your question was why you get the 'cannot find symbol' error.

```
String inWord = "hello?";
String word;
String punctuation = null;
if (inWord.contains(","+"?"+"."+"!"+";")) {
    String parts[] = inWord.split("\\," + "\\?" + "\\." + "\\!" + "\\;");
    word = parts[0];
    punctuation = parts[1];
} else {
    word = inWord;
}

System.out.println(word);
System.out.println(punctuation);
```

The scope of a variable declaration like `String word = ...` is only the block (the pieces of code inside '{' and '}') that it's in. The variables `word` and `punctuation` don't exist in the scope in which you try to print them.

You need to **declare** your variables `word` and `punctuation` in the same scope (or an enclosing scope) of where you access them in your `System.out.println`

Answer (score 0):

You could try with your custom contains function and [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)
as:

```
    public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inWord = "hello";
        String[] wordAndPunctuation = null;
        char[] punctuations =new char[]{',','?','.','!',';'};
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(inWord,new String(punctuations),true);
        int i = 0;

        if (Test.contains(inWord,punctuations)) {
            while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
                wordAndPunctuation = new String[tokenizer.countTokens()];
                System.out.println(tokenizer.countTokens());
                wordAndPunctuation[i] = tokenizer.nextToken();
                i++;
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("No punctuation in "+inWord);
        }
    }

    public static boolean contains(String str, char[] charArr){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charArr));
        for(char c:charArr){
            if(str.contains(String.valueOf(c)))
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is deprecated. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691184/scanner-vs-stringtokenizer-vs-string-split).

Answer (score 0):

You made the following errors in your code.

1.Declare the string outside the if condition

2.**inWord.contains(","+"?"+"."+"!"+";")** this is equal to **inword.contains(",?.!;")** , so the condition will fail always and it goes to else condition

1. split() will not store the value based on which you split the string

eg

```
 String string = "004-034556";

 String[] parts = string.split("-");

 String part1 = parts[0]; // 004

 String part2 = parts[1]; // 034556
```

In this the value "-" can't be stored.Hope you understand what i'm trying to convey.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend *parsing through the `String` and checking if the character is a punctuation* method:

```
String sentence = "Hello? Is this Mrs. Doubtfire?"; // Example.
ArrayList<String> chunks = new ArrayList<>();   // Will store the "non-punctuated chunks"
ArrayList<Character> puncts = new ArrayList<>();// Will the punctuations in the "sentence"
char[] punctuations = {',','?','.','!',';'};    // Store punctuations here.
int lastIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
    char c = sentence.charAt(i);
    for (char punctuation : punctuations) {
        if (c == punctuation) {
            chunks.add(sentence.substring(lastIndex, i).trim());
            puncts.add(c);
            lastIndex = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(chunks);
System.out.println(puncts);
```

---

Output:

```
[Hello, Is this Mrs, Doubtfire]
[?, ., ?]
```

*And **remember to [`import java.util.ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)**!*

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this:

```
String s = "hello!";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)?(\\W)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Word: " + m.group(1) + " | Punctuation: " + m.group(2));
}
```

Group1 will contain the word and Group2 will contain the punctuation.

Demo : http://ideone.com/ljIZFW