# Android: how to retrieve string of particular pattern from another string

Tags: android, regex, string

I have a String like `$29@@rent1@@rent2@@rent3$`. Now, all I want to retrieve is `29` and `rent1` then how can I achieve this. Can I use regular expression here?

Any response will be thankful.

Comment: is it always $ followed by 2 numbers. Will there be no 2 numbers anywhere else???

Comment: No, the number's length may very. it can be 29 or it can be 540. anything.

Comment: try to split string by $,@@ and store it to array

Comment: @Prag's can I apply regex to spli?

Comment: You can use Regular Expressions in Android...
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the StringTokenizer device.

(Edited)

```
    String STR = "$29@@rent1@@rent2@@rent3$";

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(STR, "$@");
    while(st.hasMoreElements())
        Log.v("", "Tokens: " + st.nextToken());
```

Output:

```
06-12 11:31:58.228: V/(1045): Tokens: 29
06-12 11:31:58.228: V/(1045): Tokens: rent1
06-12 11:31:58.228: V/(1045): Tokens: rent2
06-12 11:31:58.228: V/(1045): Tokens: rent3
```

Comment: `StringTokenizer` seems good. Thanks for sample. Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your string always has the format of ${some strings}$ and those some strings are elements connected by that "@@", and you want to get the first and the second elements.

If that, the first step is to remove the first and last character of the source string:

```
String new_string = old_string.substring(1, old_string.length() - 1);
```

Next, split the remaining into an array of sub strings:

```
String[] elements = new_string.split("@@");
```

Now get what you want by that arrays. Don't forget to check the length of the result array.

Here is a snippet:

```
String old_string = "$29@@rent1@@rent2@@rent3$";
// if you don't know how your string looks like, use a try - catch to
// ensure your app will not crush
try {
    String new_string = old_string
            .substring(1, old_string.length() - 1);
    String[] elements = new_string.split("@@");

    for (String text : elements) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
} catch (Exception er) {
    er.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope that help.

p.s: in case you want to use StringTokenizer for this question, I suggest you to read this answer first.

[Scanner vs. StringTokenizer vs. String.Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691184/scanner-vs-stringtokenizer-vs-string-split)

Answer (score 0):

Just try using regex with capturing and non- capturing groups. Although splitting it would make more sense(obviously..)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "$29@@rent1@@rent2@@rent3$";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\d+)(?:@@)(\\w+|\\d+).*"); // capture only 29 and rent1, ignore @@
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));

}

O/P :

29
rent1
```