# java : create string objects using a delimeter

Tags: java, string

I have input string array containing value like

> 1950/00/00;1953/00/00;1958/00/00;1960/00/00;1962/0

What could be the best way to obtain values out of above input which contains 1950/00/00, 
1953/00/00, 1958/00/00 , 1960/00/00 and 1962/0 in individual string objects?

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Use the method [`String.split(regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

Comment: @Jesper, why not put it in answer form?

Comment: You can use either `StringTokenizer` or `String.split` method http://stackoverflow.com/a/691224/2445298. Comparison is given in that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method [`String.split(regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

```
String input = "1950/00/00;1953/00/00;1958/00/00;1960/00/00;1962/0";

String[] parts = input.split(";");

for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `split()` method splits the string based on the given regular expression or delimiter, and returns the tokens in the form of array. Below example shows splitting string with (;)

```
public class MyStrSplit {

    public static void main(String a[]){

        String str = "1950/00/00;1953/00/00;1958/00/00;1960/00/00;1962/0";
        String[] tokens = str.split(";");
        for(String s:tokens){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: The split() method splits the string based on the given regular expression or delimiter, and returns the tokens in the form of array

Answer (score 0):

Another choice to split string by regular expression:

```
public class SpitByRegx
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String input = "1950/00/00;1953/00/00;1958/00/00;1960/00/00;1962/0";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9/]+);?");

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
  }
}
```