# how to use scanner class to get values into a character array?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to to read the file contents into a character array using the scanner class and I keep getting a string index out of bounds error from my code and I'm not sure what's wrong

```
    File fileName = null;
    if(0<args.length) {
        fileName = new File(args[0]);
    }
    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(fileName);
        s.useDelimiter(",");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    char[]array = new char[26];
    while(s.hasNext()) {
        for(int i=0; i<27; i++) {
            array[i] = s.next().charAt(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Curious why you set delimiter to a comma. What's your file look like? What output are you expecting?

Comment: my file looks like this: a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,g,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z

Comment: and im trying to put the characters into a character array without the commas

Comment: Okay, and do you really need a char array? You can read that one line using a CSV parser into a string array

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, your code is equivalent to the following, which has no out of bounds exceptions

```
char[]array;
while(s.hasNext()) {
    array = s.next().toCharArray();
}
```

However, after that while loop, your array will only equal the very last scanned value.

If you have individual comma separated characters, you can use the following. You do not need a loop within the existing loop

```
char[]array = new char[26];
int i = 0;
while(s.hasNext()) {
    array[i++] = s.next().charAt(0);
}
```

In any case, I suggest [using StringTokenizer rather than a Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691184/scanner-vs-stringtokenizer-vs-string-split)

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, you are trying to access a[26] but you have declared memory for 26 characters. So you can access only a[0] to a[25].

Comment: the error is coming after a[1] I should've clarified

Comment: @Josh Well, yes, 26 is after 1