# Java How to Read Data From a String (stringstream equivalent)

Tags: java, string, parsing, split

Let's say I have a String (call it s) with the following format:

```
[String] [String] [double] [int]
```

for example,
"YES james 3.5 2"
I would like to read this data into separate variables (a String, a String, a double, and an int)

Note that I come from a C++ background. In C++, I would do something like the following:

```
std::istringstream iss{s};   // create a stream to the string

std::string first, second; 
double third = 0.0;
int fourth = 0;
iss >> first >> second >> third >> fourth;  // read data
```

In Java, I came up with the following code:

```
String[] sa = s.split(" ");
        
String first = sa[0], second = sa[1];
double third = Double.parseDouble(sa[2]);
int fourth = Integer.parseInt(sa[3]);
```

However, I will have to do this to many different inputs, so I would like to use the most efficient and fastest way of doing this.

**Questions:**

- Is there any more efficient/faster way of doing this? Perhaps a cleaner way?

Comment: What do you plan on doing with these? If you just need to get these as Strings you could use Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));  which would leave you with a list of Strings.  Also, you may need to use special regex to split on all spaces, such as s.split("\\s+");

Comment: Do you actually have strings or do you have some other data to read first, like a file or a network data stream?

Comment: If you're reading input you could use a Scanner, with `next()`, `nextInt()` etc.

Comment: @CameronGrande I need these as their actual type, i.e., String, String, double, int.

Comment: @markspace Yes, I am working with strings. I am not the one in control of where I am getting them from.

Comment: C(+) is so elegant! :) ...but java so typesafe! :-))^^ Generally in java/on large scale (in c surely also more efficient) I would recommend with regex!  But when you say "many different inputs" ..i think of more structured (csv/json/fixed width, library-based) solution

Comment: @khelwood see my comment to markspace.

Comment: [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) can take a `String` as input.

Comment: @Kayaman Interesting! Thank you!

Comment: [see also (split() vs Scanner vs Tokenizer)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/691184/592355)

Comment: +1 for: ["One important difference is that both String.split() and Scanner can produce empty strings but StringTokenizer never does it."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36775514/592355)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this.  Scanner's constructor can take a string as a data source.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("12 34 55 88");
while (scan.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(scan.nextInt());  
}
```

prints

```
12
34
55
88
```

Answer (score 1):

As it has been mentioned in the comments, if this is coming from keyboard (or really from an input stream) you could use `Scanner` class to do so. However, from input sources other than keyboard, I will not use `Scanner` but some other method to parse strings. For example, if reading lines from a file, you may want to use a `Reader` instead. For this answer, I will assume the input source is the keyboard.

### Using Scanner to get the input

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Provide your input: ");
String input = scanner.nextLine();
input.close();
```

### Break the String into tokens

Here you have a few options. One is to break down the string into substring by splitting the input using white space as a delimeter:

```
String[] words = input.split("\\s");
```

If the order of these substrings is guaranteed, you can assign them directly to the variables (not the most elegant solution - but readable)

```
String first = words[0];
String second = words[1];
double third = words[2];
int fourth = words[3];
```

Alternatively, you can extract the substrings directly by using `String#substring(int)` and/or `String#substring(int, int)` methods and test whether or not the obtained substring is a number (double or int), or just simply a string.